# develop speech to text conversion api for mobile os

Tags: iphone, android, windows-mobile, webos

develop one app speech to text conversion on mobile phones.i want to develop it for supporting all mobile(android,iphone,wince,windows 7,webos).for that i would like to develop one api.

is there any way  develop api for supporting all above os.Please Let me know and suggest me.any other way

Thanks in advance

aSwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any API which is common to all the mobile platforms. In fact most of the apps you see which do such stuff on mobile, actually record the speech, send it to server, process it there and send the text back to mobile device..

However, the best open source speech to text source i would suggest is [CMU's Sphinx project](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/)...

[Brian King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98207/brian-king) has already ported it to iPhone in his [Vocal Kit](http://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit). Check if its helpful..

Good Luck